# How to detect whether a SPECIFIC Delphi version is currently running?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL application on Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I try to detect whether a specific Delphi version is currently running. So I used the `Winapi.TlHelp32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` function to search for "bds.exe":

```
function ProcessExists(exeFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  ContinueLoop: Winapi.Windows.BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: Winapi.Windows.THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: Winapi.TlHelp32.TProcessEntry32;
begin
  FSnapshotHandle := Winapi.TlHelp32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := System.SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Winapi.TlHelp32.Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  Result := False;
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if SameText(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile), ExeFileName) or SameText(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile, ExeFileName) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      CodeSite.Send('ProcessExists: FProcessEntry32.szExeFile', FProcessEntry32.szExeFile);
      BREAK;
    end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  Winapi.Windows.CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;
...
CodeSite.Send('ProcessExists(ThisBdsExe)', ProcessExists('bds.exe'));
```

Unfortunately, `FProcessEntry32.szExeFile` returns only the FILENAME without the PATH information. So I get only the information whether Delphi is running, but NOT whether a specific Delphi version is running!

Is there any way to get the PATH information from the `FProcessEntry32` structure?

Of course, I know the paths of each bds.exe that exists on my computer. But this does not work:

```
CodeSite.Send('ProcessExists(Delphi 11 bds.exe path)', ProcessExists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\bds.exe'));
```

Comment: DO NOT rely on file path for determining of which Delphi version is running. Why? Users can install Delphi at different locations. Not to mention the fact that you could also go and rename some of the folders that represent Delphi folders structure. So instead of trying to guess which Delphi version is running by folder structure you should just read Version information from `bds.exe` file instead. Unlike folder structure that would only allow you to get major Delphi versions like 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 this would also allow you to get minor Delphi versions like 10.3.1, 10.3.2, 10.3.3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The API help for [PROCESSENTRY32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-processentry32)'s szExeFile entry:

> **szExeFile**
>
> The name of the executable file for the process. To retrieve the full
> path to the executable file, call the Module32First function and check
> the szExePath member of the MODULEENTRY32 structure that is returned.
> However, if the calling process is a 32-bit process, you must call the
> QueryFullProcessImageName function to retrieve the full path of the
> executable file for a 64-bit process.

So you need to make a Module32First call and currently at least BDS is a 32bit process so you don't need to use QueryFullProcessImageName even if your app is 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

`GetModuleFileNameEx` worked for me:

```
function GetPathFromPID(const PID: cardinal): string;
var
  hProcess: THandle;
  path: array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of char;
begin
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
  if hProcess <> 0 then
  try
    if GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0, path, MAX_PATH) = 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    result := path;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProcess)
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

function ProcessExists(exeFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  ContinueLoop: Winapi.Windows.BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: Winapi.Windows.THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: Winapi.TlHelp32.TProcessEntry32;
begin
  FSnapshotHandle := Winapi.TlHelp32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := System.SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Winapi.TlHelp32.Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  Result := False;
  var ThisExeName := ExtractFileName(exeFileName);
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if SameText(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile), ThisExeName) or SameText(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile, ThisExeName) then
    begin
      var ThisBdsExePath := GetPathFromPID(FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID);
      Result := SameText(exeFileName, ThisBdsExePath);
      if Result then BREAK;
    end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  Winapi.Windows.CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;
```

Comment: You should use `QueryFullProcessImageName()` or `GetProcessImageFileName()` when available, before resorting to `GetModuleFileNameEx()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you please tell me the reason why?

Comment: I cannot find `QueryFullProcessImageName()` and `GetProcessImageFileName()` in Delphi. In which unit are they declared?

Comment: They are not declared anywhere.  Delphi is not up-to-date on all of the latest APIs.  You will have to import them yourself using your own `external` declaration, or `LoadLibrary()`+`GetProcAddress()` (or `external`+`delayed`).